# How can I create a a text box to appear when mouse moves over a vertex in jgraph?

Tags: java, mouseevent, vertex, jgraphx

I need to find a way so that when mouse moves over a vertex of the jgraph, a textbox to appear as overlay, different for every vertex. I have searched a lot in the web, but havent found anything good enouph. Any ideas how to achieve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried the approach of placing the graph into a container (ie, JPanel) and adding a  mouseListener to show a tooltip or another Jswing component (textbox) on mouse hover? 

`graphComponent.getGraphControl().addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {... /* override mouseEntered and mouseExited to show and hide the textbox */} )`

Comment: `mouseEntered` then responds to the whole panel, and not to hovering over one cell.